# strange issue on ng-repeat with jquery select2

Tags: angularjs, select, iteration, jquery-select2

trying to iterate with angular ng-repeat and display option data inside of select2 box but the data won't be displayed

**Markup**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>
        Marken
    </legend>
    <div ng-controller="Categories">
        {{categories}} //I have the data but on iterate the box doesn't populate            
        <select multiple style="width:100%" class="select2">
            <div ng-repeat="category in categories">
                <option value="AK">{{category.brand}}</option>
            </div>                                  
        </select>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I try to figure out what is cousing this issue if I iterate the options without including select2 class than I have listed datas

Comment: You are saying that the issue is because of class `select2`? Is there any events `.select2` listening to? Can you reproduce this in a fiddle.

Comment: I will try to reproduce on fiddler

Comment: a jsfiddler would be time intensive to show my problem. I have been trying the code here http://notebook2go.de/ than I made a loop outside select2 to see the problem better